# NLTK RegexParser: chunking consecutive overlapping nouns

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nlp, nltk

I want to use a RegexParser to chunk all consecutive overlapping nouns from a text, for example, I have the following tagged text:

```
[('APPLE', 'NN'), ('BANANA', 'NN'), ('GRAPE', 'NN'), ('PEAR', 'NN')]
```

I want to extract:

```
['APPLE BANANA', 'BANANA GRAPE', 'GRAPE PEAR']
```

I tried using the following grammar to avoid consuming the matched consecutive noun but it doesn't work:

```
"CONSEC_NOUNS: {(?=(<NN>{2}))}"
```

Is there any possible way to do that?

EDIT: code

```
import nltk

extract = []
grammar = "CONSEC_NOUNS: {(?=(<NN>{2}))}"
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse([('APPLE', 'NN'), ('BANANA', 'NN'), ('GRAPE', 'NN'), ('PEAR', 'NN')])

for elem in result:
    if type(elem) == nltk.tree.Tree:
        extract.append(' '.join([pair[0] for pair in elem.leaves()]))

>>> print(extract) //[]

// but I want to get ['APPLE BANANA', 'BANANA GRAPE', 'GRAPE PEAR']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegexParser` only results in **non-overlapping** chunks. I reached the following solution using NLTK's **`bigrams`**.
First, I modified the `grammar` to match any 2 or more consecutive nouns. Then I create bigrams from the result.

## The code:

```
import nltk

grammar = "CONSEC_NOUNS: {<NN>{2,}}" # match 2 or more nouns
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse([('APPLE', 'NN'), ('BANANA', 'NN'), ('GRAPE', 'NN'), ('PEAR', 'NN'), ('GO', 'VB'), 
                        ('ORANGE', 'NN'), ('STRAWBERRY', 'NN'), ('MELON', 'NN')])

leaves = [chunk.leaves() for chunk in result if ((type(chunk) == nltk.tree.Tree) and chunk.label()=='CONSEC_NOUNS')]
noun_bigram_groups = [list(nltk.bigrams([w for w, t in leaf])) for leaf in leaves]

extract = [' '.join(nouns) for group in noun_bigram_groups for nouns in group]

print(extract)
```

## The output is:

> `['APPLE BANANA', 'BANANA GRAPE', 'GRAPE PEAR', 'ORANGE STRAWBERRY', 'STRAWBERRY MELON']`

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7XANfn/1)

```
(?<=\()'([^']*)'(?=.*?\('([^']*)')
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/V2U9LC)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(?<=\()'([^']*)'(?=.*?\('([^']*)')")
s = "[('APPLE', 'NN'), ('BANANA', 'NN'), ('GRAPE', 'NN'), ('PEAR', 'NN')]"

for m in re.finditer(r, s):
    print m.group(1) + ' ' + m.group(2)
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=\()` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `(` literally
- `'` Match this literally
- `([^']*)` Capture any character except `'` any number of times into capture group 1
- `'` Match this literally
- `(?=.*?\('([^']*)')` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
  - `\('` Match `('` literally
  - `([^']*)` Capture any character except `'` any number of times into capture group 2
  - `'` Match this literally

Comment: I should clarify that I am finding a solution by using `nltk.RegexpParser` but not the standard python regex parser. Also, I have added my code edit

Comment: It is also possible for the input to be `[('APPLE', 'NN'), ('BANANA', 'NN'), ('GO', 'VB'), ('PEAR', 'NN')]` and it should give me `['APPLE BANANA']`

Comment: @ccy1997 with my current answer, you'd get the following results: [`['APPLE BANANA',
'BANANA GO',
'GO PEAR']`](https://ideone.com/VZHxIb)